# Kubernetes: Replicated stateful nginx loadbalancer with shared service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-statefulset

I searching for a possibility to have mirrored pods of a nginx loadbalancer deployment in kubernetes that alle share the same kubernetes service with one single external IP.
I tried the scenario with this statefulset config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer
  labels:
    run: loadbalancer
spec:
  serviceName: "loadbalancer"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: loadbalancer
  replicas: 4
  updateStrategy: 
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: loadbalancer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: loadbalancer
        image: /services/infrastructure/loadbalancer:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: certs
          mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: certs
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100M
```

And this service config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: loadbalancer
  name: loadbalancer
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/test/services/loadbalancer
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.31.249.3
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    run: loadbalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

All 4 pods are able to successful request the required let's encrypt SSL certs in parallel.

**The problem is that the connection via the single service from outside the cluster via the external IPv4 address resets randomly.**

How can this be prevented?

Comment: We need more info/action from your side in order to help you: 1. How are you testing it? 2. Check your firewalls rules. 3. Provide host logs.

Comment: So you mean this should be in principle possible with a replicated StatefulSet or is this way completely off?